# Laravel - routing and language code

Tags: laravel-4

I need to put a language code in my url but not when it is the default one.

Here is the code in `routes.php` file  in `Laravel 4.2`

I need root structure like:

default language => http://website.com/RegistrationStep1
other language => http://website.com/language/RegistrationStep1

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang?}', 'before' => 'localization'], function()
{

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('hello');
    });

    Route::get('registration/step1', 'RegistrationController@getRegistrationStep1');

    Route::post('registration/step1', 'RegistrationController@postRegistrationStep1');
});
```

I am getting error when I call url without the language param in url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, define your available languages:

```
# in app/config/app.php
'available_locales' => array('de', 'en', 'es', 'fr', 'it'),
```

In your `routes.php` check if the first segment of current URI is a valid language shortcut before register your prefix in route group.

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

if (in_array($locale, Config::get('app.available_locales'))) {
    \App::setLocale($locale);
} else {
    $locale = null;
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{

    //your routes here

});
```

See the link http://learninglaravel.net/language-switching-in-laravel-4/link

You can also use this package for your task: [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: i need  clean url for default language  like for  default language   url => http://website.com/RegistrationStep1
other language => http://website.com/da/RegistrationStep1     i dont required  for default language  http://website.com/en/RegistrationStep1   from your code i could not able to achieve

Comment: So remove the `en` from `available_locales` or update the first `if` statement to set `$locale` to `null` when `Request::segment(1)` is `en`.

Comment: 'languages' => array('da','dk'),           $locale = Request::segment(1);

if (in_array($locale, Config::get('app.languages'))) {
    if($locale=='en'){
         $locale = null;
    }else{
     App::setLocale($locale);
    }
} else {
    $locale = null;
}





Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{

 Route::get('/', function() {
         return View::make('hello');
     });
  
  Route::get('registration/step1', 'RegistrationController@getRegistrationStep1');
 });

Comment: http://website/registration/step1   its not working  when url call without language